# While executing script writing in python with selenium in pytest getting the message as 0 item collected and no test ran

Tags: python, pytest

this is the confest.py file present in the test cases file

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
return driver
```

this is login file present in the page package

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


class Loginchatbot():
    username_xpath = '//input[@id="username"]'
    password_xpath = '//input[@id="password"]'
    login_xpath = '//span[contains(text(),"Log in")]'

    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def set_username(self,username):
        #launching the browser
        #login in the application
        self.wait.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.username_xpath).clear()
        self.wait.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.username_xpath).click().send_keys(username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        # launching the browser
        # login in the application
        self.wait.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.password_xpath).clear()
        self.wait.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.password_xpath).click().send_keys(password)

    def clicklogin(self):
        # launching the browser
        # login in the application
        self.wait.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.login_xpath).click()
```

this is the test_login file present in the test cases folder

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from p    username = "shubhamgupta191190@gmail.com"ages.login import Loginchatbot

class test001_login:
baseurl = "https://teacher-learning-test.ef.com/"

    password = "freeBugs!"
    
    def test_login1(self,setup):
        self.driver = setup
        self.driver.get(self.baseurl)
        self.lp = Loginchatbot(self.driver)
        self.lp.set_username(self.username)
        self.lp.set_password(self.password)
        self.lp.clicklogin()
```

I am trying to design automation framework and I am new to selenium  and I am using python with selenium and pytest and while executing the above script written in test_login and function name as test_login1 getting the error message as

```
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.0, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\\Users\\GREEN EARTH\\PycharmProjects\\Chatbot
collected 0 items

================================================================ no tests ran in 0.01s \
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1. Change class name

Your test class is called `test001_login`.

`pytest` by default allows class names that start with `Test`.

Consider renaming your test class to `Test001Login`.

[Source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class)

### Option 2. Change pytest naming convention

If you want to stick with `test001_login` class name and change the standard naming convention then you need to define it in your `pytest.ini` file like this:

```
[pytest]
python_classes = test
```

[Source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions)